# boost::ptr_vector questions

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I want to have a `boost::ptr_vector` of polymorphic pointers to objects (got this part mostly working), but I am having trouble with some functionality of it.

I want to load the `ptr_vector` using a case switch to determine what child type to point to so I don't have to have multiple pointers just floating around, but when I overwrite the type the pointer is polymorphically pointing to it overwrites everything in the `ptr_vector` that was pushed using the same pointer (I think this has to do with it is storing the exact pointer) which I think can be resolved by giving it copies/[clones](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html#faq-22.5) of the objects instead of just the pointer, but I don't see where, or how to tell it how to do this.

another problem that I am having is that when the scope the pointers existed in ends all the objects in the `ptr_vector` stop existing (I have a feeling this can be resolved by fixing the problem is paragraph2)

another question that I have is how to go about removing a specific object in the `ptr_vector` for example I find that I need to remove object 5 when there are 30+ objects in the `ptr_vector` (keep in mind that I will be searching for the objects to be removed)

EDIT: I have already implemented the `clone` methods, and they are working correctly

Edit: example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
```

gameObject (polymorphic types)

```
class GameObject {
public :
    bool toBeRemoved;
    char Type;
    int name;

    virtual ~GameObject(){}
    virtual void updateObject(float duration){}
    virtual GameObject * clone(void)const = 0;
};

class Entity : public GameObject{
public:
    Entity(int _name){
        Type = 'e'; name = _name;
        toBeRemoved = false;
    }
    Entity(const Entity & _o){
        toBeRemoved = _o.toBeRemoved;
    }
    ~Entity(){}
    void updateObject(float duration){
        if(!toBeRemoved){
//          perform update work
      }
    }
    Entity * clone(void)const{return new Entity(*this);}
};

class Wall:public GameObject{
public:
    bool destroyable;

    Wall(bool destroy, int _name){
        Type = 'w'; name = _name;
        destroyable = destroy;
        toBeRemoved = false;
    }
    Wall(const Wall & _o){
        destroyable = _o.destroyable;
    }
    void updateObject(float duration){
        if((duration > 10)&&(destroyable)){
            toBeRemoved = true;
        }
    }
    ~Wall(){}
    Wall * clone(void)const{return new Wall(*this);}
};
```

object Manager (to give example of scoping)

```
typedef boost::ptr_vector<GameObject*> things; // not sure how to tell this how to clone the objects, or if I have to do it manually

class ObjectMgr{
    things objects;
public:
    ObjectMgr(){
        int entityCount = 0;
        int wallCount = 0;

        std::vector<std::vector<char>> map;
        map.resize(3);
        for(int ii = 0; ii <3 ; ii++){map[ii].resize(6);}

        for(int ii = 0; ii<6; ii++){map[0][ii] = 'w';}
        map[1][0] = 'w'; map[1][1] = 'E';
        map[1][2] = '.'; map[1][3] = 'D';
        map[1][4] = 'E'; map[1][5] = 'D';
        for(int ii = 0; ii<6; ii++){map[2][ii] = 'w';}

        GameObject* currentObject;
        for(int zz = 0; zz < map.size(); zz++){
            for(int xx = 0; xx < map[zz].size(); xx++){

                switch(map[zz][xx]){
                case 'w':   // undestroyable wall
                    currentObject = new Wall(false,wallCount++);
                    objects.push_back(&currentObject);
                    break;
                case 'E':   // entity
                    currentObject = new Entity(entityCount++);
                    objects.push_back(&currentObject);
                    break;
                case 'D':   // destroyable wall
                    currentObject = new Wall(true,wallCount++);
                    objects.push_back(&currentObject);
                    break;
                case '.':   // empty space
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        print();
    }

    void clean(){    // thinking that might need to do some kind of swapping, and then maybe pop_back()
        bool removed;
        do{
            removed = false;
            things::iterator ii = objects.begin();
//              for(int jj = 0; ii != objects.end(); ii++, jj++){
//                  if(objects[jj]->toBeRemoved == true){
//                      removed = true;
//                      // remove item here
//                      break;
//                  }
//              }
        } while(removed);
    }

    void print(){
        int count = 0;
        things::iterator reg = objects.begin();
        std::cout << "entities" << std::endl << "===================" << std::endl;
        for(int ii = 0; reg!=objects.end(); ii++, reg++){
            std::cout << count++ << ": " << objects[ii]->Type << objects[ii]->name << " " << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "====================" << std::endl << "/entities" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

main

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    ObjectMgr manager;
    std::cout << "constructed now displaying" << std::endl;
    manager.print();
    std::cout << "cleaning" << std::endl;
//  manager.clean();
    std:: cout << "displaying after cleaning" << std::endl;
//  manager.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ENOCLAIRVOYANCE: please post the code.

Comment: @n.m. thought I could ask these questions without implementation, but here is an example. program will crash while inside the first `manage.print()` I think due to scoping of the pointers

Comment: The code is a bit largish for casual inspection. You probably need to change `boost::ptr_vector<GameObject*>` to `boost::ptr_vector<GameObject>`. A vector of pointers is a great thing, but there's no need to say "of pointers" twice. Google "boost::ptr_vector" for usage examples.

Comment: @n.m. that fixed the problem of the overwriting, but I would still like to know how best to remove elements. if you could write an answer containing the suggestion, and how to remove specific elements then I will accept it.

Comment: This is *a lot* of code. When asking a question, you should always try to come up with a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/). By doing so, you will often obtain a better understanding of your problem, and perhaps find the solution on your own. And if you don't, the people you ask for help will be able to help you more easily and efficiently.

Comment: @lucTouraille I thought that I was going to be able to ask these questions without posting code at all, and all together its about 230 which is still shorter then some questions I have seen here, and it looks like more because its broken up. but I will look at shaving it